# Spring MVC, Select Special Columns in Native SELECT Query

Tags: spring, hibernate, model-view-controller, spring-data-jpa

this is my native SELECT Query in Repository

```
     @Modifying
 @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM tasks  WHERE title LIKE '%Java%' ORDER BY id DESC ", nativeQuery = true)
 List<Task> listAllTasks();
```

this works ok, but when I use custom column name instead of *, like this

```
     @Modifying
 @Query(value = "SELECT title FROM tasks  WHERE title LIKE '%Java%' ORDER BY id DESC ", nativeQuery = true)
 List<Task> listAllTasks();
```

I have this  error :
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name id was not found in this ResultSet.

any Help?

Comment: include id nice you have it in the order by

Comment: Edited your question to add the hibernate and spring-data-jpa tag. The question is relevant to those topics rather than mvc.

Answer (score 0):

The resultset doesn't have the "id" in it, you have to provide it.

You should change the way you are declaring your SQL:

```
SELECT t.title, t.id FROM tasks t WHERE t.title LIKE '%Java%' ORDER BY t.id DESC
```

Check out this sort example:[Native Queries](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference)

Answer (score 0):

1. Select * from Entity -> returns a List of Entity

Example:

```
@Query(select * from tasks)

List<Task> findAllTasks();
```

2. Select column from Entity -> returns a List of Types of the entity.

Example:

```
@Query(select t.title from tasks t)
List<String> findTitle_AllTasks();
```

**title is of the type String**

3. Select multiple columns from Entity -> returns an Object[] holding the data

Example:

```
@Query(select t.id, t.title from tasks t)
List<Object[]> findIdTitle_AllTasks();
```

So, you are retrieving String type data - title and asking to return a List of Task type. This is causing the problem. You can actually check the hibernate docs under HQL and JPQL to understand this.

Plus, you are doing a SELECT (DQL operation). @Modifying is rudimentary here as it is used for DML operations using Data JPA - UPDATE/DELETE.